# Xamarin.Forms: MvxBind MvxAsyncCommand to MvxListView ItemSelected

Tags: xamarin, events, xamarin.forms, binding, mvvmcross

I'm using MvvmCross in combination with Xamarin.Forms. Now I am trying execute a MvxAsyncCommand if an item is selected within a MvxListView.

This is a part of my code that did not work:

```
<mvx:MvxContentPage 
        x:TypeArguments="viewModels:BaseViewModel"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"    
             xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms" 
             xmlns:mvxBind="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Bindings;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:TestProject.Core.ViewModels.Settings"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="TestProjecgt.Core.Pages.Settings.TestPage"
             Title="{mvxBind:MvxBind Title}">

    <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
            <mvx:MvxListView x:Name="TestListView"
                ItemsSource="{mvxBind:MvxBind TestItems}"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HasUnevenRows="true"
                ItemSelected="{mvxBind:MvxBind TestItemSelected}">

               ....

            </mvx:MvxListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</mvx:MvxContentPage>
```

Could please someone give me a hint why it's not possible to use MvxBind to bind the ItemSelected-Event to a MvxCommand.

Thx
Phil

Answer (score 0):

If you look at an [example provided](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager/blob/2e09a479290a3810bbfca90cd4781468eff916e9/Samples/ElementPlayer.Forms.UI/Pages/HomePage.xaml) by MVVMCross, you'll notice several things off with your implementation.

Your implementation:

```
<mvx:MvxListView x:Name="TestListView" ItemsSource="{mvxBind:MvxBind TestItems}" ItemSelected="{mvxBind:MvxBind TestItemSelected}">
```

The example:

```
<mvx:MvxListView ItemsSource="{bind:MvxBind Items}" ItemClick="{bind:MvxBind ItemSelected}" SelectedItem="{bind:MvxBind ItemSelected}">
```

Obviously, adding a name `x:Name="TestListView"` in fine, but you should use the correct MvxListView Class objects for the stuff you are doing.